# How to color particular area in android mapview?

Tags: android

I am new to android map view. I have to display different color in android map view based on rainfall on particular area. Please help me to figure out this functionality.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use Map API v2 instead of the old API's (not all people aware it's out).
You can always get the updated visible region when user scrolls by setting onCameraChangeListener to your GoogleMap.

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener()
{            
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0)
    {
        VisibleRegion r = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    }
});
```

Make your layout something like

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="14"/>

<yout.package.view.ColorOverlay
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"/>
```

Add a fullscreen map fragment, and an overlay with transparent background which will draw your color zones.
The idea is to make yout custom View that will draw the colors based on VisibleRegion's northeast and southwest LatLng points and their's position on screen and make it draw above the map. That's the hardest work :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have some lat,long and based on that I have to figure out the area and fill color in it. Should this work in it?

Comment: Use a GoogleMap to get the camera center and your visible area, base d on that you draw semi-transparent colors in your hand-made ColorOverlay View based on this data. I think overlays, as suggested by akkilis is a better idea. I totally forgot about overlays writing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well in the old API also, you can show color on the map, by making the overlays of your customized shapes like circle, rectangle or anything.

Just override `draw()` in your `Overlay` class.

Having new API is always good, but its ok to use anyone for now. 
[This page](http://android-support-akkilis.blogspot.in/2013/01/map-overlays-of-custom-shape-and-color.html) tries to explain how to construct an overlay with custom shape and color.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It would be good if you provide some sample code for the same.

Comment: Overlays are a good idea. I would discourage to use old APIs. The overlays are supported in new maps too.

Comment: @DoctororDrive : Having new APIs is always good, but overlays are simple and handy. http://android-support-akkilis.blogspot.in/2013/01/map-overlays-of-custom-shape-and-color.html tries to explain a simple overlay with custom color and providing the lat long or geo point to the code

Comment: Adding GroundOverlays to new maps are quite simple.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay